# PHP array split into multiple array

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have an array of values like:

```
    Array
    (
    [0]=>Hello
    [1]=>Welcome
    [2]=>Good Programmer Good Learner
    [3]=>Thank you
    )
```

I want the array index 2 to be split separately with "Good Programmer" in one array and "Good Learner" in another array, where both of them are two different Strings. I want the Output to be like:

```
    Array
    (
    [0]=>Hello
    [1]=>Welcome
    [2]=>Good Programmer
    [3]=> Good Learner
    [4]=>Thank you
    )
```

Comment: can you share the code that generate this array ?

Comment: The condition for splitting is not clear.

Comment: Do you need a generic solution or just a solution for this array ? If generic what is the condition to split the string and to select the indexes on which such split is performed ?

Comment: Share a real example and we might be able to help you. But as it is now the question can't be answered and will be closed of unclear